# Select the last event before a specified date

Tags: mysql

Suppose that i have 2 tables descripted below :
`EventData` contains gps events for each device in almost every 60 seconds **(Means a massive amount of data)**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `EventData` (
  `accountID` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `deviceID` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `statusCode` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `latitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `gpsAge` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `speedKPH` double DEFAULT NULL);
```

`Device` contains devices informations,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Device` (
  `deviceID` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `groupID` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `equipmentType` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `speedLimitKPH` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `deviceType` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pushpinID` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL);
```

I want a query that returns the last event for each device before a given timestamp (`timestamp<$givenTimestamp`), and it has to be a single query else it will cost a lot of time. Is there any way to this ?

---

I tried this:

```
SELECT
    d.deviceID,
    d.description,
    d.pushpinID,
    e.latitude,
    e.longitude,
    MAX(e.timestamp) as timestamp
FROM
    Device as d
INNER JOIN
    EventData as e
        ON d.deviceID = e.deviceID
WHERE
    timestamp <= $time
GROUP BY
    (e.deviceID);
```

But it doesn't return what i want. it returns the last event not the last event before the given time.

Comment: @Mr.Engineer
   SELECT d.deviceID ,d.description,d.pushpinID,e.latitude,e.longitude, MAX(e.timestamp) as timestamp FROM Device as d INNER JOIN EventData as e ON d.deviceID=e.deviceID WHERE timestamp<=$time GROUP BY (e.deviceID)

Comment: Sorry, no but it doesn't return what i want. it returns the last event not the last event before the given time. @Mr.Engineer

Comment: Just do like this : `WHERE timestamp<$time GROUP BY (e.deviceID) ORDER BY e.timestamp desc limit 1`

Comment: Thanks but the `LIMIT 1` will only return 1 element, i want all the devices last event

Comment: Oh! i thought you want only 1 record. Removing limit will solve your problem.

Comment: thanks yeah sort of, but i noticed that the `ORDER BY` clause takes no effect after the `GROUP BY`, this last returns only the first event of this device not the last.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
select d.deviceID ,d.description,d.pushpinID,e.latitude,e.longitude, 
       (select max(timestamp) from EventData where deviceID=e.deviceID) as timestamp
FROM Device as d INNER JOIN EventData as e ON d.deviceID=e.deviceID WHERE 
  timestamp < '$time' GROUP BY e.deviceID
```

Comment: i ran this query and it still pending after 10 mins. @Mr. Engineer

Comment: It takes a lot of time to be executed in the server, clearly the inner select returns all the events of all the devices, and imagine if there are only 1M event for each device ... that will make millions of records !

Comment: this query crushes the server!